# Nodejs upload large file

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

I working on a Nodejs server that allow to upload large file up to 100GB. I tried using multer but when upload time reach 2 minutes, the connection is lost and upload fail.

Is anyone have any ideas. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/huge-uploader-nodejs it will work fine and will handle internet connection fails
or you can increase request time out
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.setTimeout(30*60*1000);

Comment: Thank you. I'll trying it now.

Comment: you can try also updating you server time out i edited the answer wish to solve your problem